# C language, cannot find -lglut32

Tags: c, glut

I am trying to run this code:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

But I got error:

> ld.exe||cannot find -lglut32|

I am using Windows 10.
I am using codeblocks 20.03.
I tried reinstalling codeblocks, using diffrent versions of glut and diffrent tutorials, but I have the same error all the time. I tried google for answers but it all fails. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Maybe copy `glut32.dll` to ... C:\Windows\SysWOW64 if on 64-bit Windows --- see https://blog.albertarmea.com/post/40667525183/installing-glut-on-windows

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error

Comment: I assume you are on 64 bit windows. So why are you trying to use the 32 bit version of the library? If you only have the 32 version of the library what build options did you use to generate 32 bit code in your executable?

Comment: After downgrading CodeBlocks to 17.12 it started to work.